Python Requests Post Request Returning "Method Not Allowed" on Deployed FastAPI Application Even Though the Docs Page Works Fine
I have a FastAPI application that is deployed on azure and is working fine in the built-in docs page.
However when I try and use Python requests with a post method it is stating that the method is not allowed, even though the method is clearly set as post in the code
# pdf file upload
@app.post("/pdf-upload/{market}/{data_providers}")
async def pdf_upload(file: UploadFile, market: str, data_providers: str):

This is the following code for writing request which takes in a couple of path parameters and a pdf file
import requests

market = "market"
data_providers = "data_providers"
filepath = r"filepath"
file = {'file': open(filepath, 'rb')}
url = f"endpoint/pdf-upload/{market}/{data_providers}"
response = requests.post(url=url, files=file)
json_output = response.json()

and the response I get is {'detail': 'Method Not Allowed'}
The app decorator for the FastAPI function is a post; furthermore, the requests method being used is also a post???
Please help!

Can you share the GitHub repo?

endpoint/ (in your url) is not the same as /pdf-upload/, so your URL does not match the endpoint you've included.

You might find this answer, as well as this and this helpful

@MatsLindh sorry I did not type the URL correctly, I have the pdf-upload part in the URL.

@DasariKamali Sorry I cannot share the GitHub repo because it has sensitive information in it

@Chris thank you. I wonder if it is something to do with the App set up on azure, I will investigate this first

This answer might help you as well.
